# tensorflow.nn.conv2d - input / kernel matmul

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow source code modifications.

I would like to try a variation of conv2d algorithm and want to know where exactly are the input / kernel matmul is implemented in the source code, and how to rebuild tensorflow with the modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) tutorial on how to add a new operation to TensorFlow. You will learn how to find the implementations of ops (i.e. kernels from there). There are clear instructions on compiling tensorflow from source on its github page.

For Conv2D, the operation is defined in core/ops/nn_ops.cc. It has many kernels (for CPU, for GPU, for XLA, MKL based, Eigen based). You can see them if you do: `tensorflow/core/kernels$ ls | grep conv`